# Ascending subsequences in permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm

With given permutation 1...n for example 5 3 4 1 2
how to find all ascending subsequences of length 3 in linear time ?

Is it possible to find other ascending subsequences of length X ? X

I don't have idea how to solve it in linear time.

Comment: in your example, what is the expected output? null? if it is, can you give another example where result is not null?

Comment: yes it's 0 for example : 3 5 1 2 4 6 its 5  -> 356 346 124 126 146

Comment: If you have no memory constraints, it's trivially achievable with a precomputed lookup table of all possible input sequences of length N...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the actual ascending sequences?  Or just the number of ascending subsequences?

It isn't possible to generate them all in less than the time it takes to list them.  Which, as has been pointed out, is `O(NX / (X-1)!)`.  (There is a possibly unexpected factor of `X` because it takes time `O(X)` to list a data structure of size `X`.)  The obvious recursive search for them scales not far from that.

However counting them can be done in time `O(X * N2)` if you use dynamic programming.  Here is Python for that.

```
counts = []
answer = 0
for i in range(len(perm)):
    inner_counts = [0 for k in range(X)]
    inner_counts[0] = 1
    for j in range(i):
        if perm[j] < perm[i]:
            for k in range(1, X):
                inner_counts[k] += counts[j][k-1]
    counts.add(inner_counts)
    answer += inner_counts[-1]
```

For your example `3 5 1 2 4 6` and `X = 3` you will wind up with:

```
counts = [
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 3, 1],
    [1, 5, 5]
]
answer = 6
```

(You only found 5 above, the missing one is `2 4 6`.)

It isn't hard to extend this answer to create a data structure that makes it easy to list them directly, to find a random one, etc.

Comment: Only amount of them is needed. And that's why this suprises me, because length of permutation can be : 10^6, so too long for O(N^2)

Comment: @Chris - I tried to find something that was subquadratic.  I came surprisingly close.  For instance if you needed the number of maximal ascending subsequences, the longest ascending subsequence, or several other things, I can generate it in `O(n log(n))`.  But all ascending subsequences of a given length seems intrinsically harder.

Comment: @Chris: I came up with an `O(n log(n))` algorithm, but I'd like to submit it as a Project Euler problem, so I don't want to post it publicly.  Email me at btilly@gmail.com and I'll send it to you in private.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find all ascending subsequences on linear time because there may be much more subsequences than that.

For instance in a sorted original sequence all subsets are increasing subsequences, so a sorted sequence of of length N (1,2,...,N) has N choose k = `n!/(n-k)!k!` increasing subsequences of length k.

Comment: I know that all lengths cannot be found in linear time :) Question was about fixed length : 3 or if possible another length.

Comment: A sorted initial sequence still has N*(N-1)*(N-2)/6 = O(N^3) increasing subsequences of length 3 though.

Comment: I think @user731310 wants the number of such subsequences, and not the actual sequences (because as you said, there will be N^X such subsequences at the worth case.